# htaccess RewriteRule for new domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

have some problems with my .htaccess file. I have two domains, old one and new one. i want to redirect user to the new site, when they visit the old domain.

Example:
if they visit: "olddomain.com" then they should get redirected to "newdomain.com". this is actually not that hard to code BUT i want some special redirects too. if someone trys to visit "olddomain.com/service.html" then i want redirect the user to "newdomain.com/whatwedo.hml". 
And if someone trys to visit "olddomain.com/test/hello/text.html" then i want to redirect him to "newdomain.com/something/hello.html".

i have a list of 20 specific links i want to redirect.

what i've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?olddomain.com/service.html 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/whatwedo.hml [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?olddomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

with this code every visit on olddomain.com/whatever will redirect to "newdomain.com"

can someone help me?

thank you :)

Greetings

Comment: Is your newdomain pointing to the same document root as your olddomain?

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` will contain only the domain name used in browser address bar (`olddomain.com`) but not the URI (/`service.html`), so your first condition will never be matched. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?olddomain.com 
RewriteRule ^service\.html http://www.newdomain.com/whatwedo.hml [R=301,L]
```